# Sequelize - Limit attributes when inserting to sqlite database

Tags: sqlite, sequelize.js

My issue has come up when I am inserting into a table in a SQLite database using a Sequelize model. I have a table with 4 columns: id, name, type, and description. I have a talks model which has the above schema and I can send a request to get them easily by doing `talks.findAll({attributes: [ <columns> ]});`, but I have been having an issue when trying to insert a row into the database. It complains because it defaults to inserting with the createdAt and updatedAt columnns, although I do not have those in the table. Is there a similar functionality when using `model.create()`?

Comment: Can you post your model file and the insert code?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% clear what you're asking but I'll try to answer:

When you create your model, Sequelize will automatically generate `createdAt` and `updatedAt` columns for you that are `required: true`.

When you do `model.create()`Sequelize will auto generate a `createdAt` and `updatedAt` for you to insert into your table. If you try to enter something manually into your db you'll have some trouble unless you set those fields as well.